# Assign sequence to a DB column through xml

Tags: xml, postgresql, openbravo

In openbravo ERP application, tables are created through XML files, which are parsed through SAX parser and created using a Java class GenerateEntityTask.

The sample xml file is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <database name="TABLE RESPOS_KOT">
    <table name="RESPOS_KOT" primaryKey="RESPOS_KOT_KEY">
        <column name="RESPOS_KOT_ID" primaryKey="true" required="true" type="INTEGER" size="32" autoIncrement="false">
            <default/>
            <onCreateDefault/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" primaryKey="false" required="true" type="NVARCHAR" size="60" autoIncrement="false">
            <default/>
        <onCreateDefault/>
      </column>
    </table>
  </database>
```

I want to add a sequence to the postgres database & increment the RESPOS_KOT_ID column by 1 for every insertion. I did that from sql shell as -

```
create sequence kot_sequence increment by 1  start 1;

CREATE TABLE RESPOS_KOT (
    id      INT4 DEFAULT nextval('kot_sequence') NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(60)
);
INSERT INTO RESPOS_KOT (name) VALUES ('Testing respos KOT');
```

How can i create the same in the xml format.
Any suggestions would be of great help, Thanks!!!

Comment: I have never used OpenBravo, but looking at your example I would try it using `autoIncrement="true"` maybe that gets converted to a `serial` column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that but am getting this message - 'ERROR:  null value in column "respos_kot_id" violates not-null constraint'  while inserting a record.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are created through xml's only as you mentioned , However the xml's can also be generated by openbravo ant task-[ant export.database](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/Concepts/Development_Build_Tasks#Database_export).

steps may help you to create an xml for the above table is,

1. [create a new module](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_To_Create_and_Package_a_Module#Creating_a_Module) in openbravo , indevelopment=true. OR choose any existing module and set indevelopment=true, also note down the dbprefix associated with the module.
2. Fire a query at pgadmin query promt. Use[DBPrefix](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aDevelopers_Guide/How_To_Create_a_Table#Create_new_tables_in_the_database) while creating sequence as well as tables.
3. do ant export.database
4. The xml file that corresponds to the table will get created under modules/your_module folder.